# How can i not get the heroku's 30 sec timeout error?

Tags: node.js, heroku, background, timeout, jobs

I see a lot of question on this subject but i don't get a clear answer.
i need to do simple request from the frontend to my api backend with a long request (more than 30 sec)
but heroku kill the request when it's over 30 sec. I don't understand how to override this timeout.
I see a lot of answers with background jobs but i don't understand how to implement this. My code is in Nodejs
There is my route with a long database request :

```
router.post('/export/excel', async(req, res) => {
   try {
       const data = req.body
       console.log(`Export excel for ${data.collection}`)
       console.log('data sent for /export/excel :', data)

       // Get data from the db
       const rows = await firestore.find(data.collection);
       console.log('size of rows :', rows.length)
       let stream = convertToExcel(rows);

       console.log(`Excel creation finish, sending file ...`)
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
       res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=test.xlsx`);
       res.setHeader('Content-Length', stream.length);
       res.send(stream);
   
   } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
       res.status(409).send({ error: 1, message: err.message })
   }
})
```

Comment: "I don't understand how to override this timeout"—you cannot, for good reason. You'll have to find a way to work within this time limit (and ideally a lot faster). Kick off a background job, for example.

Comment: How i told, i don't understand how to do this so i am asking for example with my code

Comment: @jeremyl where you able to solve this